# Как с помощью псевдоэлементов сделать чтобы внутри картинки была фигура, которая наполовину её закрывает?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть картинка 800 на 600 px и мне нужно чтобы её часть закрывала фигура, как это реализовать с помощью псевдоэлементов или есть другие способы?

```
.new-offer{
    background: url(image/new-offer-bg.jpg)  no-repeat 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 587px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    
    
}

.new-offer:before{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    height: 587px;
    color: #282828;
    height: 800px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: подробнее можно? примеры ваших попыток, пускай провальные но они должны быть так как stackoverflow это не бесплатная биржа труда

Comment: Что такое "фигура"?

Comment: @ksa блок с заданной высотой и шириной

Answer (score 0):

> У меня есть картинка 800 на 600 px

Такое перекрытие?

```css
.new-offer{
    background: url(https://thumbs.gfycat.com/UnfitZestyHorsechestnutleafminer-size_restricted.gif)  no-repeat 100% 100%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

.new-offer:before{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #282828;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class='new-offer'></div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам, опять помогаете)